# What are bases, really?

Tags: linear-algebra, hamel-basis

I'm taking a course in Linear Algebra right now, and am having a hard time wrapping my head around bases, especially since my prof didn't really explain them fully. I would really appreciate any insight you could give me as to what bases are! Also, can there can be multiple different bases for a single subspace?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a textbook for the course?  If not, your professor should answer questions like this for you.  If there is a textbook, see if it has an example for two different bases for one and the same vector space.

Comment: Is there something in particular about the concept of a basis that you're having trouble with? Can you give an example of a basis?

Comment: Yes, there could be multiple bases for a single space; for example, $(1,0)$ and $((0,1)$ comprise one basis for $\Bbb R^2$ over $\Bbb R$ and $(1,1)$ and $(-1,1)$ is another

Comment: Directions in space used to coordinatize points. In the plane for example, you can pick straight up and right and represent these as $x$ and $y$ coordinates. You could also pick two diagonal directions and call them $u$ and $v$ coordinates. Etc. @NoChance The plural of "basis" is "bases," I see no issue with OP's usage.

Comment: @runway44, thank you for pointing this out. I did not know this before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are subsets that “efficiently capture” the rest of the vector space. A sort of skeleton, if you will, or maybe like compressing a computer file.

This means that you can recover every other element in the space by using just the operations (scalar multiplication and addition) and furthermore there were a exactly one way (in a sense) to generate each element.

Finally, linear transformations (a main object of study) completely determined by what they do to a basis.  You can see how this makes finite dimensional vector spaces things easier if you can forget about the potentially infinite number of vectors and just focus on what a finite subset does, and trust the other elements to follow suit.

It can happen that a subspace has infinitely many distinct sets which are bases. Even for a $1$ dimensional space over an infinite field, there are infinitely many.

Answer (score 0):

While a bit late to the game, I thought another perspective might help.

---

Consider the following physical example. Now, without being too pedantic about definition, a basis for a vector space is much like a building block of a biological system. We can *build* a human body from a set of cells. That is, we can construct all aspects of our anatomy beginning with a certain set of cells (e.g. nerve cells, blood cells, germ cells, epithelial cells, etc). Thus, if we take our various tissue as *vectors*, then we have as a *basis* our cells.

But we could certainly have another *biological basis* from which to build our *biological vectors*. Namely, biomolecules. Indeed, we could express our other defined basis using this basis. Thus, our *biological vector space* has more than one *biological basis*.

Some might argue that there's not a "full correspondence" here with the mathematical notion of a basis for a vector space because, for example, how could one exhibit a change of basis from biomolecules into cells (i.e. how does one express a biomolecule as "linear combination" of cells)? But I argue the idea of *building blocks* captures the underlying spirit of a basis for a first pass.